# Dll with different processor architecture in same solution throws Bad Image format exception

Tags: dll

I am developing a Windows application in c#. I have to add a DLL to my project from another project.

The DLL which I've tried to import is with "processor architecture x 86". In my project I have DLL with "processor architecture x 64".

When I execute my project it throws a bad image format exception. Before I imported the DLL to my project it was working fine in platform target "Any CPU".  Now it throws an exception. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just build them all for the same architecture?

Comment: actually i have two third party DLL one which have x86 and other have x64.these two DLL are important for the project also.

Answer (score 0):

No this is impossible.  x64 processes must use x64 DLLs and x86 processes must use x86 DLLs.  If your OS is 64bit, all 32bit processes run under Wow64 emulation.  You can't put a 64bit DLL into that process because it won't run correctly under the emulator.  Likewise if your process is 64bit you can't have a 32bit DLL in the process because the emulator can't execute partially in the process.

You must build your DLL as the same architecture as the process.